# Would using a public IP address range on a private LAN cause issues?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

A client are having problems with their internet connection. Pings 3 or 4 times then times out for a minute or so.

The ISP have taken a look at said they can get a connection just fine to the Cisco Router, so it must be their equipment. The current setup is like this:

ISP ---> CISCO Router (ISP Managed) ---> SonicWall Firewall ---> Switch ---> PC's

I have been remotely connected and looking at the SonicWall Firewall, I noticed that the DHCP range for the LAN was set to 200.1.4.1 / 200.1.4.253.

I've only known ranges 10.0...., 192.168...and 172.16...

Could this be the cause of the issue?

Comment: The only problem that their IP range would cause is that no-one on that intranet would be able to address a public IP in the same range.

Comment: @AFH That's just the tip of the iceberg. The real owner of that ip-range can get flooded with traffic which was intended for Joey's client. And there are other, more subtle problems: Like geo-location lookups behaving strangely, just to mention one of them.

Comment: @Tonny - I disagree: the public internet has no knowledge of what goes on behind the client's router. Their public IP will be entirely independent of intranet addresses.

Comment: @AFH That's only partially true. Their own Sonicwall can get really confused about what is internal and what is external. (Believe me, I've been there...) And there is the odd piece of software that takes ip-info from the Layer4 (simplified OSI) headers in stead of Layer3. Those will get confused too. (That geo-location thing on websites that I mentioned is almost always L4 based.)

Comment: @Tonny - OK, my comments were based on theory, but I bow to your practical experience.

Comment: @AFH It got more confusing... They have a VPN connection with that range defined in the "VPN DHCP", I didn't know you could share a range with local LAN. Also, everything starts working when a 16 port switch is disconnected (has all printers / PC's connected to it)

Comment: @Joey It's NOT OK to use that range for VPN either. For the same reasons. If they mess up the cabling more then I suggest you look up Spanning-Tree and BPDU-guard. Won't fix the cabling problems but can prevent bringing down the entire LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That IP-range belongs to someone in Caracas, Venezuela.
Unless your client is actually that guy in Venezuela, this is WRONG.

So traffic that needs to go to your client, gets frequently send to Caracas instead of your client.

The only time you can safely pick an arbitrary ip-range for a local network is when that local network has NO direct connection to the internet AT ALL.
If there is a NATted connection you MUST use a safe-range like 192.168.*.*, which is specifically reserved for such use.
If there is a routed connection you will have to use REAL addresses allocated to your organization.

Comment: Thanks for that. I suspected the same. I guess this is why they have been having so many issues.

Comment: Issue actually ended up being a Ethernet cable looping back into the switch...

Comment: I hope the ip-address issue still gets addressed. It will remain a problem that needs to be solved.